# How should I store an entire database in memory using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Right now I have a static class called universe in my ASP.NET application.  The universe holds planets and all sorts of other heavenly bodies.  When the application starts I want the application to load up most of the database into memory so very few calls will need to be made to the database for the lifespan of the application.

Right now I have several lists inside the static class called universe and I am simply selecting all of the data from each table and throwing them into those Lists of their respective LINQ object.  From there I expand upon the LINQ objects using partial classes.  However I feel like there should be a better way doing this.  Sorry in advance if this is a silly question.

```
public static List<ss_planets> planets = new List<ss_planets>();
public static List<ss_moons> moons = new List<ss_moons>();
public static void create_the_universe()
{
        ssDataContext db = new ssDataContext();

        var p = (from s in db.ss_planets select s);
        foreach (ss_planets pl in p)
        {
            planets.Add(pl);
        }

        var m = (from m in db.ss_moons select m);
        foreach (ss_moons mo in p)
        {
            moons.Add(mo);
        }
}
```

Comment: You can just do `planets = db.ss_planets.ToList()`

Comment: is there no relationship between planets and moons in your model? It sounds like there should be - if so it's not expressed in your in memory lists right now.

Comment: I cannot used cached queries as the data will be changed rapidly in memory since this will represent a live model.  Also there is a relationship in the database between moon and planet in the database, I guess what I am confused about is how to best represent that relationship in memory.

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for a big bang.

Comment: Care to make any suggestions Chris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx) to retrieve all the tables you need into memory.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with doing it like that in a small application in a read-only situation. If you query these lists heavily and experience performance issues, you should consider creating Dictionaries instead. They allow fast lookup for some key.

You might also consider setting

```
ssDataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

and should wrap the context creation in a `using`-statement, which gives you:

```
using (ssDataContext db = new ssDataContext())
{
    ssDataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

    // do your thing here
}
```

Disabling object tracking will prevent you from doing things with the entities that you cannot do in this scenario anyway and may decrease initial loading times.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an in memory database?

static objects on a web site are normally a bad idea as every request could access the static object at the same time

Comment: Only if the objects are mutable.

Comment: ok, as long as your static collections do not have any mutable state including sorting and filtering. Also, I've just noticed the comment from @Caimen above that /the data will change rapidly/

Comment: I need these objects to persist over the entire application, because I am using ajax polling for communication, which hits the server approximately every few seconds to get the latest information such as a simple chat server would.  Eventually it will use web sockets once the standard becomes more secure and stable.  Obviously on every hit I can't have it pulling all this information from a database, therefore the things that change most are held in this static class.  If you have any suggestions on how to best do that, I am all ears.

Comment: I'd be thinking about a proper cache then, by which I mean not a home grown one. That way you can concentrate on your business problem and let other people worry about a clever caching engine. If you can key your query with the answer form the database then you can also control the staleness of the cached data. You may want to pre-fill the cache with you basic queries on start up. I think my ramblings are saying use the right tool for the job, in this case it sounds like a cache (or an alternative data store like RavenDb which has built in caching, as does NHibernate)